# How to query nodes exclusively in relationship with certain nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph containing Fruit, Veggie, and Dish node types, with a single relationship type of `[:in]` to indicate which ingredients are contained in each dish.

Example data:

```
create (A:Ingredient:Fruit { name: "Apple" }), 
   (B:Ingredient:Fruit { name: "Banana" }),
   (C:Ingredient:Veggie { name: "Cellery" }),
   (D:Ingredient:Veggie { name: "Daikon" }),
   (E:Ingredient:Veggie { name: "Eggplant" }),
   (F:Ingredient:Veggie { name: "Fennel" }),
   (G:Ingredient:Veggie { name: "Gord" }),
   (H:Ingredient:Veggie { name: "Horseradish" }),
   (Salad:Dish { name: "Salad" }),
   (FruitBowl:Dish { name: "FruitBowl" }),
   (Platter:Dish { name: "Platter" }), 
   (StirFry:Dish { name: "StirFry" }), 
   (A)-[:in]->(FruitBowl),
   (B)-[:in]->(FruitBowl), 
   (A)-[:in]->(Platter),
   (B)-[:in]->(Platter),
   (C)-[:in]->(Platter),
   (D)-[:in]->(Platter), 
   (C)-[:in]->(Salad),
   (D)-[:in]->(Salad),
   (E)-[:in]->(Salad),
   (F)-[:in]->(StirFry),
   (G)-[:in]->(StirFry),
   (H)-[:in]->(StirFry)
```

What I am trying to figure out, is how to query a list of Veggies that *only* show up in dishes that have *only veggies* in them.  I can get the first part (a list of Dishes that only have veggies) with this query:

```
match (d:Dish) 
where not ((:Fruit)-[:in]->(d)) 
return d
```

This returns `Salad` and `StirFry` as I expected.

Is there a way to then query all Veggies that *only* belong to that set? (in this example, only Veggies E,F,G, & H) If not, or if its really hard to do, is there a better way to structure this data to make that apparent relationship more obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to the solution. You can `match` the veggies in the first pattern. The `where` clause will remove not desired dishes.

```
match (d:Dish)<-[:in]-(v:Veggie)
where not ((v)-[:in]->(:Dish)<-[:in]-(:Fruit))
return v
```

the output will be something like:

```
╒═══════════════════╕
│v                  │
╞═══════════════════╡
│{name: Eggplant}   │
├───────────────────┤
│{name: Horseradish}│
├───────────────────┤
│{name: Gord}       │
├───────────────────┤
│{name: Fennel}     │
└───────────────────┘
```

Comment: This returns some veggies I don't want, however.  Cellery is in the Platter dish, which also contains some Fruits.

Comment: @slushpupie ok, edited the constraint to prevent veggies that are part of dishes with fruits.

Answer (score 2):

You can continue your query from the one you started by adding an additional `MATCH` clause:

```
MATCH (d:Dish) 
WHERE NOT ((:Fruit)-[:in]->(d))
MATCH (veggie:Veggie)-[:in]->(d)
RETURN (veggie)
```